# Why Firebase in Flutter Web on Android Studio is giving me unknown error?

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, authentication, web

When I first created the project and integrated Flutter with Firebase, Flutter was still at version 2.0. Flutter was updating and I never had any problems. Now, recently, with the Flutter 3.10 update and after spending more than 1 month without touching the project, when I try to insert an email, any email, even if it is a new or old user, with or without a password, firebase always gives me the same error message: unknown error.

Here I have more details of this error:

> [firebase_auth/unknow] An unknown error occurred: FirebaseError: Firebase: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password. (auth/wrong-password).

The funny thing is that the error talks about the password, but actually, like I said, it has nothing to do with the password. When I reset the user's password, part of the message that talks about the password error disappears, but the rest of the error message remains.

This problem only happens when I select Chrome in Android Studio and click the green Play button in Android Studio. When I run it with the `--release` parameters at the end:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit --release
```

With Chrome that opens with the above command, everything works normally. My app is also hosted on Firebase Hosting, connected with my domain. And, accessing the application through the domain connected to Firebase Hosting, I can also enter the application normally, without even an error message.

So my question is only in relation to Android Studio, why this problem happens?

Here is my complete code from the authentication screen via email:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_utils/src/get_utils/get_utils.dart';
import 'package:pineapplepay/view/login/email/EntrarComSenha.dart';

class EntrarComEmail extends StatefulWidget {
  const EntrarComEmail({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EntrarComEmailState createState() => _EntrarComEmailState();
}

class _EntrarComEmailState extends State<EntrarComEmail> {
  final TextEditingController _controllerEmail = TextEditingController();

  String _mensagemErroEmail = "";

  bool btnDesativado = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controllerEmail.addListener(_verificarValoresControllerText);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool lightMode =
        MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.light;

    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: lightMode ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                  (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 55,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Insira seu endereço de e-mail",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 34,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: lightMode
                          ? const Color(0xff939094)
                          : const Color(0xff939094),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(4),
                            ),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: _controllerEmail,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              cursorColor: lightMode
                                  ? const Color(0xffE91482)
                                  : const Color(0xffE91482),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                decorationColor:
                                lightMode ? Colors.black : Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                fontFamily: "Unbutu",
                                color: lightMode ? Colors.black : Colors.black,
                              ),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email),
                                border: const UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                hintText: "fulano@gmail.com",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontFamily: "Unbutu",
                                  color: lightMode ? Colors.black : Colors.black,
                                ),
                                label: Text("E-mail"),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontFamily: "Unbutu",
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                errorText: _mensagemErroEmail != ""
                                    ? _mensagemErroEmail
                                    : null,
                                filled: true,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: TextButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                          lightMode
                              ? const Color(0xffE91482)
                              : const Color(0xffE91482),
                        ),
                        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                        )),
                        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                          const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 20,
                            bottom: 20,
                            left: 50,
                            right: 50,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (!btnDesativado) {
                          _validarCampos();
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Confirmar",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                          color: lightMode ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        return true;
      },
    );
  }

  void _validarCampos() {
    if (_controllerEmail.text.isNotEmpty) {
      if (_controllerEmail.text.contains("@")) {
        if (_controllerEmail.text.length > 4) {
          if (GetUtils.isEmail(_controllerEmail.text)) {
            setState(() {
              btnDesativado = true;
            });

            _logarUsuario();
          } else {
            snackBar("Por favor insira um e-mail válido.", "Ok.");
            setState(() {
              _mensagemErroEmail = "Por favor insira um e-mail válido.";
            });
          }
        } else {
          snackBar(
              "Você deve definir um e-mail maior do que 4 caracteres!", "Ok.");
          setState(() {
            _mensagemErroEmail =
                "Você deve definir um e-mail maior do que 4 caracteres!";
          });
        }
      } else {
        snackBar("Você esqueceu do @", "Ok.");
        setState(() {
          _mensagemErroEmail = "Você esqueceu do @";
        });
      }
    } else {
      snackBar("Você não pode definir um e-mail fantasma!", "Ok.");
      setState(() {
        _mensagemErroEmail = "Você não pode definir um e-mail fantasma!";
      });
    }
  }

  String generateRandomString(int len) {
    var r = Random();
    const _chars =
        'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890';
    return List.generate(len, (index) => _chars[r.nextInt(_chars.length)])
        .join();
  }

  void _logarUsuario() async {
    String senha = generateRandomString(10);

    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _controllerEmail.text,
        password: senha,
      )
          .then((firebaseUser) async {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
        snackBar(
            "Ocorreu uma causalidade do destino em uma probabilidade tão improvável que este acontecimento deveria ser impossível. Portanto, você deve fazer o login novamente.",
            "Ok.");
        setState(() {
          _mensagemErroEmail =
              "Ocorreu uma causalidade do destino em uma probabilidade tão improvável que este acontecimento deveria ser impossível. Portanto, você deve fazer o login novamente.";
        });
      });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        btnDesativado = false;
      });

      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        snackBar("E-mail não cadastrado.", "Ok.");
        setState(() {
          _mensagemErroEmail = "E-mail não cadastrado.";
        });
      } else {
        if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
          _abrirTelaSenha();
        } else {
          if (e.code == "too-many-requests") {
            snackBar(
                "E-mail bloqueado. Entre em contato com o suporte para restaurar seu e-mail",
                "Ok.");
            setState(() {
              _mensagemErroEmail =
                  "E-mail bloqueado. Entre em contato com o suporte para restaurar seu e-mail";
            });
          } else {
            snackBar("Ocorreu um erro e o erro é: $e", "Ok.");
            setState(() {
              _mensagemErroEmail = "Ocorreu um erro e o erro é: $e";
            });
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      snackBar("Ocorreu um erro e o erro é: $e", "Ok.");
      setState(() {
        btnDesativado = false;
        _mensagemErroEmail = "Ocorreu um erro e o erro é: $e";
      });
    }
  }

  void _abrirTelaSenha() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => EntrarComSenha(
          key: widget.key,
          email: _controllerEmail.text,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void snackBar(String content, String label) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(content),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: label,
        onPressed: () {
          // Some code to undo the change.
          print("Tocou no SnackBarAction");
        },
      ),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  void _verificarValoresControllerText() {
    if (_controllerEmail.text.isNotEmpty) {
      if (_controllerEmail.text.contains("@")) {
        if (_controllerEmail.text.length > 4) {
          if (GetUtils.isEmail(_controllerEmail.text)) {
            setState(() {
              _mensagemErroEmail = "";
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _mensagemErroEmail = "Por favor insira um e-mail válido.";
            });
          }
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _mensagemErroEmail =
                "Você deve definir um e-mail maior do que 4 caracteres!";
          });
        }
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _mensagemErroEmail = "Você esqueceu do @";
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _mensagemErroEmail = "Você não pode definir um e-mail fantasma!";
      });
    }
  }
}

Edit:

Ok, so, the problem is gone. I dont know why, I have no idea. But, I tried to run with the green button on Android Studio and everything works fine. So I will mark this as done.
```

I already cleaned the Android Studio cache, I already ran the flutter clean command, I already formatted the computer. Firebase now supports app integration in Flutter. As I explained earlier, when I created my application in Flutter, this option did not exist. So, trying to fix my problem, I tried to use this new integration, I followed the steps correctly but the exact same error persisted. Also, I've already generated new keys in the Google console and I've already replaced the new key in my project. I've even used ChatGPT to give me ideas, but even he wasn't able to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with Firebase auth on Flutter web, Firebase "email-already-in-use" when I receive this error code and I use error.code it says unknown, but when I run on release mode then the error.code says "Email already in use"

Comment: In my case in release mode there is no error, everything works perfectly. This error I mentioned in my initial question only happens if I click the green "Play" button in Android Studio. Both in Chrome and Edge. I am in doubt if this problem is related to the Android Studio IDE or Firebase.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was, In debug mode I don't get the correct error code I get "Unknown" on error.code, While on release when I enter an email to sign up that already exists, I successfuly get correct message which is "Email already in use". 
So if your code works fine with flutter run --release on Web then it's the same as I mentioned, and if you press the green "Play" button that starts with debug mode and like I said debug mode has this issue,

Comment: Very good! Thanks for clarifying, so in this case, it seems that what is causing the error must be the new version of Flutter 3.10. I even updated all the packages but the same behavior continues. I believe this problem can be fixed with a new Flutter update. I'll stay tuned for when a new update comes out I'll update. Maybe the problem will be fixed. Thank you so much for putting a light at the end of the tunnel!

Comment: Okay so I was able to partially solve the problem. To solve it, I had to put an if in the default: of my switch-case to check the error.message content. The check is: if (error.message!.contains("wrong-password") { _abrirTelaSenha();}
That way I managed to solve it partially. And I say partial because the problem is related to Firebase, because the return code is being sent in error.message and not in error.code, so the API returns me unknow which is the same thing as null. Well, I hope that the Firebase team fixes this grotesque error that broke my entire application.